# PHP str_replace with an offset

Tags: php, offset, str-replace

I have the following output:

```
Item
Length : 130
Depth : 25
Total Area (sq cm): 3250
Wood Finish: Beech
Etc: etc
```

I want to remove the Total Area (sq cm): and the 4 digits after it from the string, currently I am trying to use str_replace like so:

```
$tidy_str = str_replace( $totalarea, "", $tidy_str);
```

Is this the correct function to use and if so how can I include the 4 random digits after this text? Please also note that this is not a set output so the string will change position within this.

Comment: `preg_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
$exp = '/\(sq cm\): \d+/';


echo preg_replace($exp, '', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can practice php regex at http://www.phpliveregex.com/

```
<?php

$str = '
Item
Length : 130
Depth : 25
Total Area (sq cm): 3250
Wood Finish: Beech
Etc: etc
';

echo preg_replace("/Total Area \(sq cm\): [0-9]*\\n/", "", $str);
```

> ```
> Item
> Length : 130
> Depth : 25
> Wood Finish: Beech
> Etc: etc
> ```

Comment: I think, performance-wise, hlscalon's suggestion (`substr_replace`) is preferrable compared to `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
$strToSearch = "Total Area (sq cm):";
$totalAreaIndex = strpos($tidy_str, $strToSearch);
echo substr_replace($tidy_str, '', $totalAreaIndex, strlen($strToSearch) + 5); // 5 = space plus 4 numbers.
```

If you want to remove the newline too, you should check if it's \n or \r\n. \n add one, \r\n add two to offset. Ie. `strlen($strToSearch) + 7`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
  preg_replace('/(Total Area \(sq cm\): )([0-9\.,]*)/' , '', $tidy_str);
```